# Empty xsl result in eclipse using Apache FOP 2.3

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I have XSLstyle sheets and some XML example files to change into PDFs. I've verified that the XSL sheets are correct (the PDF generated using the command line version of `Apache-FOP 2.3` are consistent and no errors are thrown). When I use `Eclipse > Run > Transform` with `Xalan 2.7.1` the result is the same as the `FO` output of the command line version.

However I've since then tried to implement the embedded version in java and it hasn't been working. I've checked the `FO` result and it appears to be void of any `FO` markers, the result file only containing the text value of the XML. This results in a `fop.fo.ValidationException`.

I suspect it has something to do with conflicting versions of some library or maybe a missing parameter in a property file, but so far I haven't been able find the error.

**EDIT**
I can't share the XSL and XML files, but here is the my java snippet:

```
  private void transformToPdf(Document docJDOM, OutputStream destination, File xslFile)
throws SAXException, IOException, JDOMException, TransformerException {
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(FOPCONFIGFILE);
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, destination);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new 
    StreamSource(xslFile));
    Source source = new DOMSource(transformJdomToDom(docJDOM));        
    Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Where FOPCONFIGFILE is my fop.xconf file (I'm using the default file provided in the Apache-FOP website), docJDom is a JDomDocument of the xml file I wish to transform and xslFile is the xslStylesheet I wish to apply. I've checked the values of docJDom, xslFile and they are correct.

**EDIT 2**
I've just tried outputting the fo result file using the embedded code
by changing this

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new 
    StreamSource(xslFile));
    Source source = new DOMSource(transformJdomToDom(docJDOM));        
    Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

to this

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
Source source = new DOMSource(transformJdomToDom(docJDOM));
Result result = new StreamResult(destination);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

And checked the resulting fo for errors. I was able to find multiple lines such as `<fo:table-row height="0.5cm"/>` which are the source of the error. 
However I then transformed the same XML file using the same XSL stylesheet but with the Apache-FOP 2.3 binary distribution, the resulting fo was correct and did not contain those errors.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code snippets viz. Java, XSL,, XML?

Comment: @AniketV unfortunatly I can't for the xsl and xml files. They're company property. I'll add my java snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have located the error: the XSL stylesheets are correct, the problem is that the module that is using these files copies them to a different folder and uses those copies to do the pdf transformation. By running the unit tests individually, my corrected XSL sheets weren't copied, and thus I was using the old incorrect versions.